# railis new failing on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

When I run `rails new [application]` on Ubuntu 13.10, I get the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

It looks like I have this gem installed though:

```
$ gem list | grep coffee-rails
coffee-rails (4.0.1)
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Bundler page](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html):

> The specifier ~> has a special meaning, best shown by example. ~> 2.0.3 is identical to >= 2.0.3 and < 2.1. ~> 2.1 is identical to >= 2.1 and < 3.0. ~> 2.2.beta will match prerelease versions like 2.2.beta.12.

As such, version 4.0.1 of your gem is still not the specified one, that is between 3.2.1 and <3.3.

Just run

> bundle install

Or, if you were unable to get a project directory with a valid Gemfile:

> gem install coffee-rails --version 3.2.1

And it should install a compatible version.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. After I got that error, I just went ahead and ran `bundle install` on the newly created app folder. It installed the missing dependencies and `rails new` is working now.